# HTML generation in JS code

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know your thoughts about HTML code generation in my JS code.

I just think that the `html.push("<tag>" + something + "</tag>")` style pretty annoying.
I've already tried something with templates inside my HTML file (and put some placeholders therein), and then used its content to a replace the placeholders to my real values.

But maybe you guys have other ideas, possibly one using jQuery.

Comment: What did you not like about a templating solution?

Comment: could you give more details and/or an example? I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to construct HTML to call something.innerHTML = myhtmlstring, or are you trying to use the DOM appendChild / replaceChild functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has javascript template plugins like [jBind](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jBind) and [jTemplate](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jTemplates).  I haven't used them myself but I do recommend jQuery whenever possible.

A note on html generation, it is not searchable by search engines in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is the way to go.  You can do things like this:

```
// create some HTML
var mySpan = $("<span/>").append("Something").addClass("highlight");
```

- it is cross-browser compatible,
- it is an easy to use syntax

There is also a [templating plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerytemplate).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`createelement`](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_document_createelement.asp), [`appendchild`](http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/met_element_appendchild.asp), and [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_anchor_innerhtml.asp) to do this.

Here's [an article from A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dynanav/) that uses these functions in the process of generating a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of how [PrototypeJS](http://www.prototypejs.org) handles [templates](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/template).

First you create an instance of the Template class and pass it a string containing the template HTML.

```
var tpl = new Template('Here is a link to <a href="#{link}">#{sitename}</a>');
```

Then you pass it data containing the values to replace within the template.

```
$('someDiv').innerHTML = tpl.evaluate( {link: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', sitename: 'StackOverflow'} );
```

In the above example, I have a div with id="someDiv" and I'm replacing the contents of the div with the result of the template evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

Resig has a little [blog entry](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) on creating a very lightweight template system.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of JQuery function that support this. In particular, you should look at `append(content)`, `appendTo(content)` `prepend(content)` `prependTo(content)`, `replaceWith(content)`, `after(content)`, `before(content)`, `insertAfter(content)`, and `insertBefore(content)`.